# Does $wgSpamRegex require any Extensions?

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

Does [$wgSpamRegex](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgSpamRegex) require any Extensions in MediaWiki version 1.23.5 for it to work?

On the one hand, that page in the Manual says it's "built in" to MediaWiki, but then someone on the Talk page [mentioned](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual_talk:$wgSpamRegex#.24wgSpamRegex_is_not_working_in_my_wiki) it's not working and another user recommended installing the [SpamRegex Extension](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:SpamRegex), which is obsolete but solved that users problem.

So which is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manual seems up to date. `$wgSpamRegex` is a core function, and does not require any additional extensions.

(The discussion you are referring to is from 2008, and the MW version mentioned there is 1.13.)

Answer (score 0):

The information on the Manual page is correct. `$wgSpamRegex` is a built-in configuration variable and can be used without any extensions :)